# grab wanted bits of 'find' output, using awk, from an SSH call

Tags: regex, bash, ssh, awk

Using an SSH call, I need to run a 'find' command on a remote system as follows:

```
/usr/bin/find $mountpoint -type f -mtime +1095 -ls
```

(where $mountpoint is a defined path)

I then want to grab field 7 of the output (bytes)

```
6668   56 -rw-r--r--   1 46978    32840       51652 Jun 24  1999   ./wafs2/BF_BRN_S1/Cta/updatesxp/OfficeSP1/FILES/WINDOWS/FONTS/ELEPHNT.TTF
6811   80 -rw-r--r--   1 46978    32840       76588 Oct 15  1999 ./wafs2/BF_BRN_S1/Cta/updatesxp/OfficeSP1/FILES/WINDOWS/FONTS/POORICH.TTF
6670   56 -rw-r--r--   1 46978    32840       54324 Jun 24  1999 ./wafs2/BF_BRN_S1/Cta/updatesxp/OfficeSP1/FILES/WINDOWS/FONTS/ELEPHNTI.TTF
6804   56 -rw-r--r--   1 46978    32840       55824 Jun 29  1999 ./wafs2/BF_BRN_S1/Cta/updatesxp/OfficeSP1/FILES/WINDOWS/FONTS/ROCC____.TTF
```

... and total the count for each line returned, like this:

```
/usr/bin/find $mountpoint -type f -mtime +1095 -ls | /bin/awk '{sum+=$7} END {print sum}'
```

and return the value of sum.

In a local bash session on the remote host, this works flawlessly and returns a value like this:
1.61468e+12

However, it doesn't work when I try to run the same command via SSH:

```
$file_find_cmd = "/usr/bin/find $mountpoint -type f -mtime +1095 -ls | /bin/awk '\"{sum+=\$7} END {print sum}\"'"; 
print "here's \$file_find_cmd:$file_find_cmd\n"; 
$nas_find_cmd = "$ssh nasadmin\@$vnx -q '. /home/nasadmin/.set_nas_env_vars; $file_find_cmd'"; 
open($file_find_handle,'-|',"$nas_find_cmd") or die "Unable to run command $nas_find_cmd: $!\n";
```

I *have* tried escaping the $ in $7 but haven't made any headway ... so I don't think it's that.

Help ? Thanks.

Comment: What is your non-working SSH command line?

Comment: Essentially it's this:

`$file_find_cmd = "/usr/bin/find $mountpoint -type f -mtime +1095 -ls | /bin/awk '\"{sum+=\$7} END {print sum}\"'";

print "here's \$file_find_cmd:$file_find_cmd\n";

$nas_find_cmd = "$Ssh nasadmin\@$vnx -q '. /home/nasadmin/.set_nas_env_vars; $file_find_cmd'";

open($file_find_handle,'-|',"$nas_find_cmd") or die "Unable to run command $nas_find_cmd: $!\n";`

Comment: If you control the target system, consider putting this into a script on that system, and call that from SSH.  I'm sure you can make it work by finding the magic quote syntax, but multi-level quoting like this is difficult and fragile.

Comment: Hmm.  If I need to loop through several hundred values of $mountpoint via list @mountpoint, though, I could see that being a problem.

Essentially, 1) get a list @mountpoint; 2) for each value, run the SSH command to the remote host to do the find and count up the value of field 7, then return it; 3) do something with each value; 4) next

Comment: +1 with @Peter even when not controling the target system (vnx storage system I think) it should be handable to copy the script with scp to a temp location (using tempfile) before executing it via ssh. exemple: `TMP=%BT%tempfile%BT%;  echo 'echo this is a test' > $TMP; sh $TMP` (Bad escaping of backticks in code, replace `%BT%` by ` in previous exemple)

Comment: So make your script take the mountpoint as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure of what you want to accomplish but here's a try:

```
#!/bin/sh
vnx=$1
mountpoint=$2
my_ssh="ssh -q $vnx /usr/bin/find $mountpoint -type f -mtime +1095 -ls | /usr/bin/awk '{sum+=\$7} END { print sum }'"
result=`$my_ssh`
echo Result is $result
```

Works for me in the form `./findremote.sh target_server /var` output:

```
Password:
Result is 226758
```

(it still ask for a password as I don't have any authorized_keys on the target system)

At this point you have the value wished in `$result` for post processing in this local script...

Hope it will help you

edit for a precision: when launching commands by ssh there's no need to quote them, anything after the host would be took as command to process, so for your specific exemple sourcing a file before, just add it before like this:

```
my_ssh="ssh -q $vnx . /home/nasadmin/.set_nas_env_vars; /usr/bin/find $mountpoint -type f -mtime +1095 -ls | /usr/bin/awk '{sum+=\$7} END { print sum }'"
```

If you want an extra test and executing the find only if the sourcing worked, change the `;` by `&&`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by escaping the wanted column's placeholder var with more than one backslash; my lack of experience with awk and regexp's in general led me to believe that escaping it with one backslash (i.e. print \$7) instead of three (print \\$7) would suffice.

```
$nas_find_cmd = "$Ssh -q root\@$vnx \". /home/nasadmin/.set_nas_env_vars; /usr/bin/find $mountpoint -type f -mtime +1095 -ls | /bin/awk '{ sum=sum+= **\\\$7**} END { print sum }'\"";
```

I am now just about 0.00042% smarter.

Thanks all!